# HttpPost in Android partially working

Tags: android, http-post

I'm trying to send some data to a webpage that uses Apache/MySQL configuration by using an Android device. Here's a snippet of code I'm using (IP address is fictionnal) :

```
    final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.2/test.php");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {  

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submitted", "1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", country));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adminArea", admin));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subAdminArea", subAdmin));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zip", zip));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", adrs));                 

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = null;

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

This code is executed once I press the "Submit" button and inserted into a database on the server side. The problem I have is that I receive only partially the data sent and I have to press multiple time the "Submit" button to make sure all the data as been inserted. As an example, the first time I hit the button, only the country is inserted. Then the adminArea, then the "subAdminArea", etc...

Could it be a problem with the code shown above or could it be a problem on the server side?

Comment: if you have access to the server, why not check what is arriving at the server by viewing the server logs or using WireShark? That way you can confirm what the server is receiving which may help youto better understand where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Agreed, can't see anything wrong with your code - although I  recommend using AsyncTask over Thread - and think you need to check things server-side.

Comment: I found the problem. Some queries made to the database were returning empty results wich caused some errors. Since I didn't have an interface to see the response from the server, I didn't see those errors. Looking trough the logs helped to find the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

do check if everything on the server side is of the same case. I had the first letter of the wrong case and was needlessly wasting my time.

Comment: The `ArrayList` constructor taking an `int` value sets the *initial* size of the ArrayList and does not prevent you from expanding it further.